# Retrieving HTML Pieces

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

So I have this HTML here:

```
<div id="verify-purchase-modal" data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Buy Item</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
<form action="/Catalog/ProcessPurchase" method="post">              <div></div>
                <div class="catalog-modal-image">
                        <img src="http://t6ak.roblox.com/cd4fad953f57e86e537da262b3503e04" alt="General Badblox" />

                </div>
                <div>
                    Would you like to buy the <strong>"General Badblox"</strong> Package
                    from ROBLOX for
                        <span class="currency-robux">400</span>?
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a no-margin-grid add-large-margin-top clear">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="9EZgfWvmFbfVWWSvuIhMrWWs6E2XmjONlejy5JJRYQh5KBbttyCtH/ve1KcPq1MbLYnj6ktT8SyGfFrWRYshUMLUI1mmthTs1KJNizlPG8T809is5Y0ZJYJyqaTCmnom2P6vVpmnZATlqsFtN4pVhd1QH94cZbLU2eszES4+QLeES2Cv" />
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CurrencyType must be a number." data-val-required="The CurrencyType field is required." id="CurrencyType" name="CurrencyType" type="hidden" value="1" />
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AssetID must be a number." data-val-required="The AssetID field is required." id="AssetID" name="AssetID" type="hidden" value="98755232" />
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field UserAssetOptionID must be a number." data-val-required="The UserAssetOptionID field is required." id="UserAssetOptionID" name="UserAssetOptionID" type="hidden" value="0" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Buy Now" data-theme="d" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a id="cancelPurchase" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="f">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="dialog-footnote">
                        Your balance after this transaction will be <span class="currency-robux">11,910</span>.
                    </div>
</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I used VB to get that from a website.  In the line where it says "400?" I want to extract the 400, so I saved all that HTML as a string.  I tried to do the simple and just use a substring to get it, but I keep getting an OOB (out of bounds) error.  Keep in mind I am trying to do this in visual basic.

```
        Dim daHtml As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml
    Msg(daHtml.Substring(daHtml.IndexOf("currency-robux"">"), daHtml.IndexOf("</span>?")))
```

Comment: A solution involving http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

In VB, the substring works differently than in other languages. Wrongly, in my opinion. Instead of being substring(startIndex, endIndex) it is substring (startIndex, length). So you are looking for something that starts at:

```
daHTML.IndexOf("currency-robux"">")
```

and goes the length of:

```
daHTML.indexOf("</span>?")
```

And therefore, going outside of the bounds of the string.